# Live reload a remote website?

Tags: html, browser, livereload

Can LiveReload reload a remote website?  If not is there any other way to reload a remote website when its css, html,or javascript is edited and saved on the server to be seen the developer on its local machine?

When run guard I get this warning

Warning: you have a Gemfile, but you're not using bundler or RUBYGEMS_GEMDEPS
08:10:15 - INFO - Guard here! It looks like your project has a Gemfile, yet you are running

> [#] `guard` outside of Bundler. If this is your intent, feel free to ignore this
>   [#] message. Otherwise, consider using `bundle exec guard` to ensure your
>   [#] dependencies are loaded correctly.
>   [#] (You can run `guard` with --no-bundler-warning to get rid of this message.)

then guard exits with a very long line the end of which is

```
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.14.1/bin/_guard-core:11:in `<main>'
```

Anyway the html, css,and js I am editing is on remote VPS and even before guard exits I see update of the website.  I also install the LiveReload add-ons for Chrome and Firefox Developer Edition.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting to Stack Overflow. Your question is too broad, and asking for advice on which library to use is off-topic

Comment: I did not ask which library to use,please read again.

Comment: Sorry my fault, but in any way, your question is too broad. Please give more detail about the problem. Do you have any error message while you are trying to LiveReload, which tools and browsers are your uses? The more detail you give about the question, the better answers you gain.